# Ruby: Is it ok for a method to return an object of different types?

Tags: ruby, oop

Is it a good idea to return an object whose type changes depending on the method’s inner logic?

E.g.:

```
class Error
  attr_reader :details

  def initialize(details)
    @details = details
  end
end

def div(a, b)
  return Error.new("error: division by zero") if b == 0
  a / b
end

# declare foo, bar here
result = div(foo, bar)
if result.is_a?(Error)
  puts result.details
else
  puts "result of division: #{result}"
end
```

As you can tell, the **div** method returns either an **Error** instance, or an **Integer** instance.

Is it a bad practice (and why)? Does it violate the single responsibility principle?

By the way, I do get that another option would be to return a hash { error: error, div_result: div_result }, but I’m curious if it could be replaced with only one single object.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't do this. If you want to raise an exception, do so, then handle it in the caller. It's still breaking the Law of Demeter, but at least you're only returning one thing or handling an exception. Filling callers with conditional logic is definitely an anti-pattern.

Comment: This goes against good codingfu. Errors / Exceptions should be thrown / raised not returned like this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be reinventing the wheel. Ruby already has [Exception Handling](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html) and it also includes a [`ZeroDivisionError`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/ZeroDivisionError.html) which is raised when dividing an integer by zero:

```
def div(a, b)
  a / b
end

begin
  result = div(6, 0)
  puts "result of division: #{result}"
rescue ZeroDivisionError => e
  puts "error: #{e.message}"
end

# prints "error: divided by 0"
```

Note that your `div` method isn't needed either, you can just as well write `result = 6 / 0`.

---

> Is it a good idea to return an object whose type changes depending on the method’s inner logic?

"type" is a difficult term in Ruby. I assume you mean something like *"an instance of a specific class"* like an integer or a string? It really depends. For most methods it would certainly be a good idea, but there are good exceptions to this rule.

[`Integer#+`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Integer.html#method-i-2B) for example returns a result based on its argument: (you could argue that these are all subclasses of [`Numeric`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Numeric.html))

```
1 + 2    #=> 3       (Integer)
1 + 2.0  #=> 3.0     (Float)
1 + 2r   #=> (3/1)   (Rational)
```

[`String#index`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/String.html#method-i-index) usually returns an integer but it may also return `nil` to indicate "not found":

```
"hello".index("o") #=> 4     (Integer)
"hello".index("x") #=> nil   (NilClass)
```

[`Array#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) returns whatever object is stored at the specified index, thus having arbitrary return values:

```
a = [123, :foo, "bar"]

a[0] #=> 123    (Integer)
a[1] #=> :foo   (Symbol)
a[2] #=> "bar"  (String)
a[3] #=> nil    (NilClass)
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer. Of course, the code from the question is just a simple example to illustrate my point. My real code is much more complicated. But I get the main idea.

Comment: @mate you can of course create you own error classes (see [custom exceptions](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Exception.html#class-Exception-label-Custom+Exceptions)), but those should inherit from [`StandardError`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/StandardError.html) and be raised, not returned. If the condition you are trying to handle is not "exceptional" but rather common, you might want to return something like `nil` instead. Ruby tends to be light-weight in that regard.